# Hive optimization for sort performance

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I have a very simple Hive table created as:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE input_data (
    key string,
    value string
  )
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION 's3://bucket/input/';
```

Now from the above table I want to generate **single file** in S3, where all the records are sorted by the keys as follows:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sorted (
    key string,
    value string
  )
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION 's3://bucket/output/';

  SET hive.exec.reducers.max=1;
  SET mapred.reduce.tasks=1;

  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sorted
    SELECT * FROM input_data
    ORDER BY input_data.key;
```

My question is, what Hive optimizations can I explore to see if the sorting can be made faster? Currently to sort an input table with 50 million rows, it takes around 1 hour 20 minutes on a cluster where each host has 64 GB RAM and 32 CPUs and 640 GB SSD. Of course, since I am forcing a single reducer to generate a single file, only one host is used in the reduce stage of the INSERT query.

My keys are largely arbitrary strings of around 60-75 characters with a lot of common prefixes of around 20 characters (in case it is relevant).

I am using Hive 2.1.1 running on Tez 0.8.4 (AWS Emr release label 5.3.0)

Any pointers?

Comment: What is the point of all this?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz  What do you mean? My use case requires me to generate a single sorted file. I am asking if there are ways to make this go faster.

Comment: This is exactly the question - why do you need a single **sorted** file?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz the downstream consumer of this data is a system that converts this file into a memory mapped file for extremely fast query - for this the system needs the keys sorted to be able to build the memory mapped file.

Comment: I have an idea, I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz appreciate the help. I have the data and hardware available with me to experiment - let me know if I can try a few things out.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a table in hive and then move the files to bash and merge them?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - didn't get that. Are you suggesting we move the data from the Hive table to local disk and perform the sorting in bash using the ```sort``` command?

Comment: No, I thought we might split the data and sort each part individually and then extract the parts to the local shell and merge them.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz AFAIK that is exactly what Hive does under the hood, so that wouldn't help much.